# disable radio buttons of a particular column in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table of radio buttons as shown in the below picture and if the user checks one radio button then that selected `radio button column` should be disabled and the user can check only one radio button in a row and for this, I have given the `same name` to the radio buttons of each row so that user can select only one radio button for a row. now the problem is that I am unable to disable the radio button of the checked column. I have used checked and selected interchangeably. any help is very much appreciated. thank you.

[table of radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpwWp.png)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let heading of columnHeadings[selectedScenario]">
      {{heading}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3];">
    <td *ngFor="let loop of columnHeadings[selectedScenario]">
      <input type="radio" name="{{i}}"> Correct
      <input type="radio" name="{{i}}"> Partial
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is checkboxs? And provide sample data of `columnHeadings`.

Comment: I have edited the question @ZunayedShahriar

Comment: name attribute is valid only in forms

Comment: but its working for rows @Double-expresso

Comment: It is invalid on td

Answer (score 1):

You have to track from which row you are selecting a radio button and then disable it.

**HTML:**

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let heading of columnHeadings[selectedScenario]">
      {{heading}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let i of iterables;">
    <td *ngFor="let loop of columnHeadings[selectedScenario]">
      <input [disabled]="disabledRows[i]" type="radio" name="{{i}}" (change)="disableRow(i)"> Correct
      <input [disabled]="disabledRows[i]" type="radio" name="{{i}}" (change)="disableRow(i)"> Partial
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**TypeScript:**

```js
selectedScenario: string = "scenario";
iterables = [0,1,2,3];
disabledRows = this.iterables.map(m => false);
columnHeadings = {
  scenario: [
    "Most Effective Response",
    "Second Most Effective Response",
    "Trird Most Effective Response",
    "Least Effective Response"
  ]
};

disableRow(index: number) {
  this.disabledRows[index] = true;
}
```

Working solution at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4zyyg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you don't want disable the columns, only need that an option is not selected in the same column, else early you get into a situation when you can not select any value

For this, give values to the radiobuttons and use an array to store the values

```
values=[]; //declare an empty arrays

  <tr *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3]">
    <td *ngFor="let loop of columnHeadings[selectedScenario];let j=index">
      <input  type="radio" name="{{i}}" [ngModel]="values[i]" 
                 (ngModelChange)="change($event,i)" [value]="j" > Correct
      <input  type="radio" name="{{i}}" [ngModel]="values[i]" 
                 (ngModelChange)="change($event,i)" [value]="10+j" > Partial
    </td>
  </tr>
```

See that values get the column selected (0,1,2,3) if you select correct and 10 + the column selected if you choose partial (10,11,12,13) (e.g. a value of 12 indicate that you choose the "Trird Most Effective Response partial" and a value of 1 indicate you choose "Second Most Effective Response correct")

The function "change", give value to this.values[index] and loop over "values" making null a value if is in the same column

```
  change(value,index)
  {
    this.values[index]=value
    this.values.forEach((x,i)=>{
      if (i!=index && x%10==value%10)
           this.values[i]=null
    })
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t2covx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **checked disabled** to your radios like this:

```html
<input type="radio" checked disabled name="{{i}}">
```

Comment: It will check the last checkboxes and disable all of them.